# How to interleave strings by alternating chars?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Suppose I've the following strings

```
std::string st1 = "ab";
std::string st2 = "xyz";
```

I want to interleave these strings by alternating chars so that the output is

```
std::string output = "axbyz";
```

If one of the strings is longer than the other, the result is just the concatenation of the remaining chars from the longer string.

How can I do this in C++?

I could concatenate using '+'.

Comment: That's not code that will compile so it's hard to answer.  But if you have types of std::string you can concatenate them with a '+' operator.

Comment: Take out a blank piece of paper, and a pen. Write down, in simple, plain steps, a logical algorithm to perform this operation. [After discussing your proposed algorithm with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), once your rubber duck agrees that your algorithm works, simply translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Well, you do it by taking chars one by one from each of the strings, and concatenating them into a new string. Which part of this are you having difficulti with? Looping over the strings? Getting character from a string at a given index?

Comment: While I agree that the question is rather easy, I can't see how it is "too broad". Also arrogantly telling the OP to "do it himself" is hardly encouraging a new user.

Comment: So more merging than concatenating...  The next time, please show at least some attempts to solve it.

Comment: @sygi I think OP got plenty of advice on how to do this, and how refine their question to be "less broad", so I don't see how that is an arrogant response. But this question is very clearly a "please solve my homework for me" request, and SO is not a homework writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shall **alternate** the characters of each string:

```
std::string res = "";
for(int i = 0; i < std::max(a.size(), b.size()); i++){
    if (i < a.size())
       res += a[i];
    if (i < b.size())
       res += b[i];
}
```

Comment: why not simply: sum them directly instead of a loop?

Comment: You better hope that you have a high quality compiler that can figure out that `std::max(a.size(), b.size())` is a constant, and needs to be evaluated only once, instead of on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Because the OP want the chars to be _alternating_.

Comment: `string::size()` is has a O(1) complexity and extracting it is a premature optimization.

Comment: Opps ! Sorry, I didn't realize that he wanted to alternate the output.